# Matrix construction

Tags: r, matrix

This should be a fairly easy question. Under i have a matrix PX. I want to write the matrix without numerical values & with variables instead. However, when i do so i get the error code "object "p" not found.

I guess i have to undefine "p" and "q" somehow, how do you do that?

```
PX <- matrix(c(0, p, 0, 0, q, 0, 
           q, 0, 0, p, 0, 0,
           q, 0, 0, 0, 0, p,
           0, 0, q, 0, 0, p,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 6, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
```

Kind Regards,

Peter

Comment: If it a character, it needs to be quoted.

Comment: Sorry i don't undersand.  do i write "p <- undefined" or something?

Comment: I meant `c(0, 0, "p", 0, "q")` etc.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I needed. 

Also, is there someway to show the matrix in a nice & representable way instead of just writing "PX"

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Well its the answer to a long question, i want to precent it nicely & cleanly instead of looking "cody" . However, I guess you need to use latech or something to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help. But it won't do the final "mathy" job of putting the giant parentheses/brackets around the values in rows and columns. For that you do need LaTek or maybe MathML.

```
> p <- 'p'  # need a value (not necessarily "p") for the unquoted symbol - `p`
> q <- 'q'
> PX <- matrix(c(0, p, 0, 0, q, 0, 
+            q, 0, 0, p, 0, 0,
+            q, 0, 0, 0, 0, p,
+            0, 0, q, 0, 0, p,
+            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
+            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 6, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
> PX
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "0"  "p"  "0"  "0"  "q"  "0" 
[2,] "q"  "0"  "0"  "p"  "0"  "0" 
[3,] "q"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "p" 
[4,] "0"  "0"  "q"  "0"  "0"  "p" 
[5,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0" 
[6,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1" 

> print(PX, quote=FALSE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] 0    p    0    0    q    0   
[2,] q    0    0    p    0    0   
[3,] q    0    0    0    0    p   
[4,] 0    0    q    0    0    p   
[5,] 0    0    0    0    1    0   
[6,] 0    0    0    0    0    1
```

It would also be possible to define rownames and colnames, so if you wanted to suppress the "cody" bracketed numbers, you could define all the names to be "".

```
> colnames(PX) <- rep("",6)
> rownames(PX) <- rep("",6)
> print(PX, quote=FALSE)

 0 p 0 0 q 0
 q 0 0 p 0 0
 q 0 0 0 0 p
 0 0 q 0 0 p
 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 1
```